# How to get the exit code?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following shell statement:

```
LC_CODE=$(   
  docker run --rm --name argocd-test \
    -e DO_AC=$DO_AC \
    -e K8S_CLUSTER=k8s-databaker-io \
    -e ARGO_SERVER=cd.databaker.io \
    -e ARGO_USERNAME="$ARGO_USERNAME" \
    -e ARGO_PW="$ARGO_PW" \
    -e IMAGE_URL=hub.databaker.io/ui/argo-ui-test \
    -e IMAGE_VERSION=0.1.2 \
    -e CHARTS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/charts.git \
    -e GITOPS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/gitops.git \
    -e APP_TYPE=ui \
    -e APP=argo-ui-test \
    -e APP_URL="$LC_APP_URL" \
    -e APP_TLS_SECRET="dev-cert-staging" \
    -e GIT_USER="$GIT_USER" \
    -e GIT_AT=$GIT_AT \
    -e NAMESPACE=dev \
    argocli:latest /sh/main.sh;
  echo $?
)
```

the values that is saved into `LC_CODE` is:

```
echo $LC_CODE
<===========================================>
Check if all variables are set
<===========================================>
1
```

However I would like to get the exit code and not the text `Check if all variables are set`.
How can I get the exit code?

Comment: `docker run ...; LC_CODE=$?`

Answer (score 2):

Your current code stdout result of all sub-shell commands into the `LC_CODE` variable. I suggest run the commands as following:

```
docker run --rm --name argocd-test \
    -e DO_AC=$DO_AC \
    -e K8S_CLUSTER=k8s-databaker-io \
    -e ARGO_SERVER=cd.databaker.io \
    -e ARGO_USERNAME="$ARGO_USERNAME" \
    -e ARGO_PW="$ARGO_PW" \
    -e IMAGE_URL=hub.databaker.io/ui/argo-ui-test \
    -e IMAGE_VERSION=0.1.2 \
    -e CHARTS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/charts.git \
    -e GITOPS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/gitops.git \
    -e APP_TYPE=ui \
    -e APP=argo-ui-test \
    -e APP_URL="$LC_APP_URL" \
    -e APP_TLS_SECRET="dev-cert-staging" \
    -e GIT_USER="$GIT_USER" \
    -e GIT_AT=$GIT_AT \
    -e NAMESPACE=dev \
    argocli:latest /sh/main.sh;

LC_CODE=$?
```

You can stdout result of your docker command into another variable by:

```
result=$(docker ...)
LC_CODE=$?
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider sending the output of the docker command to `/dev/null` as follows:

```
LC_CODE=$(   
  >/dev/null docker run --rm --name argocd-test \
    -e DO_AC=$DO_AC \
    -e K8S_CLUSTER=k8s-databaker-io \
    -e ARGO_SERVER=cd.databaker.io \
    -e ARGO_USERNAME="$ARGO_USERNAME" \
    -e ARGO_PW="$ARGO_PW" \
    -e IMAGE_URL=hub.databaker.io/ui/argo-ui-test \
    -e IMAGE_VERSION=0.1.2 \
    -e CHARTS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/charts.git \
    -e GITOPS_URL=gitlab.com/databaker.io/gitops.git \
    -e APP_TYPE=ui \
    -e APP=argo-ui-test \
    -e APP_URL="$LC_APP_URL" \
    -e APP_TLS_SECRET="dev-cert-staging" \
    -e GIT_USER="$GIT_USER" \
    -e GIT_AT=$GIT_AT \
    -e NAMESPACE=dev \
    argocli:latest /sh/main.sh ;
  echo $?
)
```

For emphasis, I put the `>/dev/null` at the beginning of the command (this is not a popular syntax).  Of course, you can put it before the `;`  if you prefer.